# Unable to run npm from Powershell

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, npm, path-variables

This is my path

```
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> $Env:Path
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Python27;C:\Users\Chiefkes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Chiefkes\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Chiefkes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Propellerhead Software\ReWire\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Propellerhead Software\ReWire\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Chiefkes\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Chiefkes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Chiefkes\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Chiefkes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Chiefkes\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Chiefkes\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

When I run `npm -v` I get the following:

```
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> npm -v
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'npm' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation.At line:1 char:1
+ npm -v
+ ~~~~~~.
```

Comment: Can you confirm `npm.exe` is visible by running `Get-Command npm -CommandType Application`?

Comment: I ran `Get-Command npm -CommandType Application` and got the following:

`Application | npm | 0.0.0.0 | C:\Windows\system32\npm`
`Application | npm.cmd | 0.0.0.0 | C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd`
`Application | npm | 0.0.0.0 | C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm`

Comment: Ok so for some reason I had an empty npm file in system32 and that seems to have been the culprit. Deleting this file fixed my issue